# Unexpected token '<' Error (npx create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've setup a new react app using npx `create-react-app my-app`.

In the index.html file I want to import a javascript file in the head like so

`<script src="/src/.../file.js"></script>`

However, I keep getting Unexpected token '<' error. I can't do an import as it creates loads of errors and I want to be able to use some functionality in these scripts across the site.

Any ideas how to reference this file? Previously in other projects we use webpack but this config doesn't seem available in this project.

Comment: This looks ok, please provide more code.

Comment: I found it is only problematic if im pointing to local file, however if I use CDN like cloudfare it has no error.

Comment: Then it is clear. The slash shows to the webroot configured in the vhost in the browser (absolute path).

Answer (score 0):

If your js files are located in the /public/ folder then you can import it like this:

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/.../file.js"></script>
```

If it is located in /src/ folder, you can simply import it to your `index.js` file, and it will be available across your React application. Remember that order of imports matters here.

```
import './.../file.js';
```